# How to open print version of the site in a new page with jsf?

Tags: java, url, jsf

I need to make a link which opens print version of current page in a new tab. I already have correspondent css-file. But I don't know how to specify when this file should be used instead of standard.

The simplest way is quite good. If I was using JSP I would simply add get parameter to print-link URL. Is there any way to achieve similar results with jsf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use EL to specify the CSS file dynamically, here's an example which checks the presence of the `print` request parameter (thus, `<h:outputLink value="page.jsf?print" target="_blank">` would suffice):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${not empty param.print ? 'print.css' : 'normal.css'}" />
```

You can also retrieve it as a bean proprerty the usual JSF way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<h:outputText value="#{bean.cssFile}" /> " />
```

If you're on Facelets instead of JSP, then you can also use unified EL in template text:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{bean.cssFile}" />
```

If you actually don't need a "print preview" tab/page, then you can also just specify the `media` attribute in the CSS `link` and let the link/button invoke `window.print()` during `onclick` instead of opening in a new tab.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normal.css" media="screen, handheld, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

When the page is about to be printed, the one specified by `media="print"` will automatically be used instead.

Comment: I've already specified the media attribute but for some reasons client wants a link.

Comment: Fine, I expanded the answer with few more possibilties than just `${param}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add get parameters to any JSF link by using the f:param tag.

```
<h:outputLink value="/somepage.xhtml" target="_blank">
   <h:outputText value="Link to Some Page"/>
   <f:param name="someparam" value="somevalue">
</h:outputLink>
```

This will render something basically like this:

```
<a href="/somepage.xhtml?someparam=somevalue" target="_blank">Link to Some Page</a>
```

You can add multiple params with more f:param fields. Alternatively, if it's static, you can just add it as part of the outputLink itself.

```
<h:outputLink value="/somepage.xhtml?someparam=somevalue" target="_blank">
   <h:outputText value="Link to Some Page"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

The problem, of course, being that you cannot do this and trigger server-side events. I've yet to figure out how to do this from a POST back and get it in a new tab.